# How can I keep text identical across several text boxes in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I have a layout with many (2x2) postcard-size cards on an A4 page, which are going to be cut into individual pieces after print. The postcards should remain identical. Each has multiple text fields. I would like text changed in one of those fields to be automatically updated in the corresponding fields in the other postcards. How do I achieve this?

In the following example, if I change e.g. "Vor genau" in one place, I would like that change to be reflected on the other side as well.

[image]

Comment: I think it will be much better to understand your question if you put a graphic example.

Comment: @Danielillo I added a screenshot.

Comment: Have you explored Master Pages?

Comment: @Scott I know that master pages can have fixed elements repeated on each page, but then I'm unsure how to repeat my (postcard) pages so that they will appear in fixed positions on the final A4 print. So I didn't pursue that further, and instead used "Step and repeat".

Comment: @FelixDombek What is it that makes it so special that it can not be done in a simple Find / Replace? I'm trying to understand the complexity of your question because all the answers that come to mind are too simple to do.

Comment: @Danielillo Find/Replace wouldn't work well for multiline changes. Besides, the same text could occur in an unrelated other field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use Master Pages
- Set up 1 postcard on a master page

[image]

- Apply that master page to *document* pages
- To change text on a *specific docent page* **hold down <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the text frame**. This will override *that* text frame on *that* page, allow you to change it for that particular postcard.

[image]

[image]

- Other pages will still have the *original* master page applied. Therefore you can use the same procedure to edit any additional page-specific text needed.

[image]

Since the core of the postcard is all set up on a master page, it will *always* be in the same position on any document page with the master applied to it.

If you need to edit one text frame for all pages, and the text frame has *not* been overridden on the pages, simply edit the *master page* - master page changes will be reflected on the document pages (unless overridden).

---

This is essentially the "reverse" of what you may be thinking in terms of procedure. Rather than having a text frame that propagates itself to other document pages in order to remain the same, you create *everything* so it propagates to *all* document pages and its *all the same* - then you edit what needs to be *different*.

---

**If you wish to have *multiple iterations* of the postcards on one sheet.....**

Set up a single postcard file as I've described above. When all the text is correct, export to a high quality single-page PDF.

Open a **new** InDesign document the size of your output (A4), then use `File > Place` to *place* each page of your PDF as an image. You can then position the PDF images however you'd like on one page. Simply print this "ganged" page. The original PDF data will be used for output.

If **edits** are then needed to the postcards... edit the *single page* file and output to PDF again. Open the "ganged" document, update the links, and print.

Comment: I still don't get how to print several of these individual pages on exactly the right positions on an A4 page (exactly adjacent, for seamless cutting), but this would likely make for a different question.

Comment: @FelixDombek Yes, if you are doing multiple iterations on one page, then this may not be as useful. **However**, you *can* set things up this way, then export to a PDF. And open a *new* InDesign file and *place* each page of the PDF, and position the placed images however you'd like. Then merely output the ganged PDF for printing. I've added to the answer.

Comment: You don't even need to export a PDF - you can place .indd files in other .indd files.