# How do I layout small pages on a large print sheet?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121939/how-can-i-keep-text-identical-across-several-text-boxes-in-indesign-cs6/), where I used "step and repeat" to arrange several identical "postcards" on an A4 sheet side-by-side, to be cut after printing. See attached example.

Now to keep these smaller postcards identical, I was advised to use master pages of postcard size instead of step-and-repeat on an A4 page.

This poses the problem: How do I arrange the pages created from these master pages on an A4 sheet for seamless cutting? I.e. how would I emulate the "repeat with raster" part of my previous workflow in InDesign CS6?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the answer there to include this...

**If you wish to have *multiple iterations* of a layout printed on one sheet.....**

- Set up a single page file containing 1 of the items ([as described previously](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121939/how-can-i-keep-text-identical-across-several-text-boxes-in-indesign-cs6/)).
- When all the text is correct, export to a **high quality single-page PDF**.
- Open a **new** InDesign document the size of your output (A4)
- Use `File > Place` to *place* each page of your PDF as an image.
- You can then position the PDF images however you'd like on one page.
- Simply print this "ganged" page. The original PDF data will be used for output.

If **edits** are then needed to the postcards... edit the *single page* file and output to PDF again. Open the "ganged" document, update the links, and print.

While it's not very commonly something one would think of for InDesign, a 2-file workflow can be exceptionally helpful if you need the gang items.

The reality is you don't even need a PDF. You can place InDesign pages into another InDesign document. So you could theoretically skip the PDF entirely. I find using a PDF in this manner as sort of a "fail safe". If something where to happen to the original file, or edits to the original file were incomplete, the PDF helps identify when output was generated last. But that is, admittedly, my preference.